# How to avoid doing unnecessary computation when looking for a matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I was given this simple exercise, compute the determinant:

> $$
>     det\begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & 4 & 5 \\
>     2 & 4 & 6 \\
>     3 & 4 & 7 \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$

it turns out to be zero, but I was wondering if there is something I could have noticed before doing any computation, and realise the determinant was zero.

if there is, what should one pay attention to, to know beforehand whether the determinant is zero?

Comment: You could notice that column 3 is column 1 plus column 2.

Comment: If the columns are linearly dependent, then the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the 1st and the 2nd column you get the 3rd